# R looping through categorical variables

Tags: r

I have the variables "data$LINE" and "data$STATE" and I want to use a loop to rename them with out the "data$".  Then I want the same loop to input "LINE" and "STATE" into my code, but I also want "data$LINE" and "data$STATE" to run in the loop as well.  The reason is that I have two graphing functions, one depending one the name i.e. "LINE", the other depending on "data$LINE" and I want these two graphs to run for "LINE" and "STATE" so after the loop, 4 graphs are made.

The code is:

```
for(variable in c(data$LINE, data$STATE)) {
variable_name <- sub("data$", replacement = "", "data$variable", fixed = TRUE)
whatevergraphingfunction(variable)
differentgraphingfunction(variable_name)
}
```

This is not working right (it doesn't seem to create the 2 variable_names), any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add another ) after data$STATE), so the first line would be `for(variable in c(data$LINE, data$STATE)) {`

Comment: That was just a typo in this question. Thanks for pointing it out, I have edited it

Comment: Your variables are not named `data$LINE` and `data$STATE`; you have a data.frame (or list) named `data` which contains variables `LINE` and `STATE`. The `data$` specifies where R should look for them. If you really don't like typing it, check out `with`.

Comment: Its not that I don't like typing it, its just that one of my graphs looks at the variable names like "LINE" and the other looks at the data frame like "data$LINE".  I just want these two graphs to be made together for each variable

Comment: Are you talking about the axis labels? Set them separately, or wrap the graphing function in `with`: `with(iris, plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width))`

Comment: No I'm talking about two separate graphs (Well one table and one graph).  My version without the loop goes like so:    variable <- "data$LINE"     variable_name <- "LINE"  then     table.desc <- describe(as.factor(eval(parse(text = variable)))) pandoc.table(table.desc$values) and that creates the first table.  Then I have    quick_table(variable_name) which creates another graph

Comment: @Killian answerers are confused because your question is unclear. To clear it up, you could make a reproducible toy example that actually runs in R, where 1) data is defined, 2) whatevergraphingfunction and differentgraphingfunction are real functions from base R or some package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is in `for(variable in c(data$LINE, data$STATE))` , because you are trying to concatenate 'symbols' start with strings for the for function, and them convert them to names after sub() has run.

```
#start with variables as strings
for(variable in c("data$LINE", "data$STATE")) {  
  #Remove the 'data$'
  variable_name <- sub("data$", replacement = "", variable, fixed = TRUE)

  # convert strings back to names
  as.name(variable)     
  as.name(variable_name)

  # Graph
  whatevergraphingfunction(variable)
  differentgraphingfunction(variable_name)

}
```

Without knowing how `LINE` and `STATE` will be used, I am not sure if you need to call them as names. If not, just delete the `as.name(variable_name)` line.

Let me know if this worked for you.